# Flex grid not rendered correctly on Safari - no height on flex items

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

Here is a simple HTML table running on both Chrome and Safari:

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.rows-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

.row-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>TEST</h1>
  <div class="rows-container">
    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On Chrome everything looks fine, the rows are being rendered properly.

But on Safari the rows are not getting the correct height, overrendering one above another (see pic below).
[image: Safari bug]

This is a simple flex use, so seens to be something that I'm missing.

How can I properly fix the code so that it shows correctly on both Safari, Chrome and IE (Edge) ?

I'm using Safari 12.1.1 on MacOS Mojave.

Comment: That is pretty wild to see how different Safari renders it. Is chrome the intended layout? Why height: 100% on everything?

Comment: Yes, Chrome is the intended layout. The height on flex container is necessary as this component is added to a chain of objects. On flex item is just a try to make it Worley...

Comment: Looks good in Safari for me: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JQKygq

Comment: @jons, looks good for me too on codepen... But not when you click on "Run Code Snippet" above I get this erroneous behaviour, as well as on my application.... very strange...

Comment: Very odd. Are you sure the height being set to 100% isn’t causing some part of it?

Comment: Doesn't work on JsFiddle also. Removed the height 100% on flex item and problem remains... Check [https://jsfiddle.net/cox123456a/gow1a7sk/1/#&togetherjs=R90ThRnNln]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari renders `flex-shrink` differently than other browsers.

Just disable it on the row items.

Add this to your code:

```
.row-container {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u35gf1mq/3/)

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.rows-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

.row-container {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* new */
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid cyan;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>TEST</h1>
  <div class="rows-container">
    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My reasonings were around finding a way to make the row height grow, but the solution is about making it not to shrink... Thanks for helping - works like a charm.